# Windows App Focus: Why does it require a click?

Tags: wpf, focus

When I have 2 apps open and one has the focus but I want to execute a command in the other app, it requires a click to regain focus and another to execute the command.  Is there some good reason why I couldn't take focus on MouseOver?  I'm working with a WPF app if that is pertinent.  TIA

EDIT:  Oddly enough the MouseOvers work without focus.

Comment: I made a WPF app with a button on it just now, and I'm able to click the button whether or not the window has focus. Is your application an Office add-in? Is the command triggered by a button or some other method?

Comment: Yes, you're right and I'm feeling sheepish!  I was going the other way (Wpf to AutoCAD) and was wondering what is the prevailing sentiment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this.  This is not a standard way of working in Windows, so you will confuse your users.  People are used to clicking into an application (or tabbing) to provide focus.

However, this is a [configurable setting via the Accessability Tools in Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/hover.aspx).  It can be enabled by choosing "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse" globally.  Let your users specify this behavior if they want it.

Comment: Thanks Reed (And everyone).  Will do!

Answer (score 4):

The setting is configurable at a system-wide level. You should *never ever* override the user's current setting regarding this.

[MS Windows Vista -- focus follows mouse](http://jhv.blogs.com/falloutshelter/2009/01/ms-windows-vista-focus-follows-mouse.html) (There's also a link on how to do it on XP.)

Edit: Normally, you can click a button on a form and both bring focus to the window *and* click it at the same time. The origins of the current setting "eating" the initial mouse click that brings focus to a window started as a fix to a bug in the Ribbon UI. The discussion is somewhere in this video: [The Story of the Ribbon](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2008/03/12/the-story-of-the-ribbon.aspx). Sorry I can't narrow it down more than that, but at least the video is a great insight and work watching -  maybe you can send a message to Jensen Harris if you need a faster answer.

**Edit 2:** I just added a button to a WPF window, and I'm able to click it as long as I can see it - whether or not the window has focus.

Comment: Outstanding video so far.  As noted above, of course, you're right and thanks again!

Comment: This behavior of "eating" the initial mouse click when clicking is what I'd consider normal. But apparently it seems to have been reverted for Windows applications with a ribbon, at some point in the last ten years, while most other apps seem to have adopted that behavior.

Comment: The referenced video can now be found at https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX08/UX09. The discussion of eating mouse clicks is at 1:06:30-1:08:45.

Comment: I was led here because I'm trying to figure out an intermittent issue with Slack. Frequently I have the Thread sidebar open. When I'm in another application and then click on the thread reply textbox, the Slack app takes the foreground but seems to "eat" the click to some degree because it doesn't put the focus where I expect it to, meaning when I type a reply it goes in the open channel instead of the thread. This will give me some ideas to think about.

Answer (score 0):

You can take focus on MouseOver manually

Comment: Yes, but is there a good reason why I shouldn't?  It seems like most apps behave this way.  Is there a UI guideline that would make this rude/evil?

Comment: Its just a convention in windows.  You can get utilities which make windows behave in a more X like fashion so that they grab focus automatically as you pass your mouse over them.

Comment: well if it's your app for internal use only than just do what you want. If the program for public distribution i'd recommend to keep the defaults

Comment: @Jherico: No need to get utilities - it's a configurable built-in Windows setting.

Comment: well it maybe confusing. if a person move his mouse to click on 'Start' button but insted he actives your application it a bit wired.